# Problem looping audio on android app

Tags: android, audio, loops

Due to login confusion, i'm repeating this question. If any moderator sees this, i'd like to keep this one current, as I no longer can access my former login.

A bit of a problem has presented itself to me. I am trying to play a sound continously looping in my android app.

With MediaPlayer: MP3 plays alright, but there is a gap at the end which does not exist in the file. I read it had to do with the decoder, and that ogg should work. Tried using ogg, but still get the gap, which is definitely not on the file.

With SoundPool classes and ogg (using this fellow's interesting class: http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html),

the sound starts, and a fraction of a second later, it restarts. so I get a stutering half a second of the beginning of every file, without advancing further, because it is always going back to the beginning.

Is there something really wrong with media player and it's ability to loop audio? How about the freakishy stuttering soundpool?

Thank you very much for any assistance!

Note: Karthi_Heno suggested I do this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("music.ogg");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            textView.setText("Couldn't load music file, " + e.getMessage());
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
```

However, when i do this, getassets gives filenotfound, even though there IS a filein assets. any thoughts either on thisassets problem, or my audio loop question?

thanks. Yep, i'm an android newb alright, can't even get sound to loop alright.

Comment: Managed to get that code going. However, as with my first usage of media player i still get a pause between loops, thus not getting a continuous sound

Comment: What did you have to change to get it to work (even with the pause)?

Comment: I actually used by brain and noticed that I had placed the asset in the assets folder of the wrong bloody project:)

Comment: so, as things are, i can loop with mediaplayer and get a sound gap, or with soundpool and the thing goes sort of nuts, repeating itself quite fast, as if only getting the first half second of the sound

Comment: have you heard about SoundPool,you can try that, its easy as playing mediaplayer...!!!

Comment: yes, I have also tried sound pool, but as i mentioned, it will play half a sec of the sound then go back to the start, etc, looping indeed, but only through the first few instants